# Task scheduler : How to detect that a usb device is unplugged?

Tags: usb, scheduled-tasks

I want to launch a Powershell script when a usb device is unplugged. To accomplish that I would like to use a scheduled task but I don't know what event trigger I should use.

I already know that to detect when a USB device is plugged in, you have to use the following event trigger : (in Event Logs) Application and Service Logs/Microsoft/Windows/DeviceSetupManager/Admin but I am looking for the event trigger to use to detect when the device is unplugged.

Comment: There should be another event for when a device is unplugged.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the name of this event or at least a method to find other than trying every events... I found how to detect the plug in of a usb device on the internet but so far I haven't found how to detect that this device is unplugged on forums

Comment: Navigate to that log, unplug your device and see whatever message pops up in that log?